# Colocar distinto css a una misma clase de un plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin

Soy novato en javascript y css, y quiero modificar el css de un plugin de wordpress, de manera que cada botón tenga un color(imagen) diferente. Cuando modifico un botón se modifica todo. No tengo forma de modificar el hmtl para ponerle un id diferente a cada botón, creo que una forma sería usando javascript.  Al estar limitado usé imágenes para los botones. Logre poner una imagen de color botón verde a uno de los botones pero no pude cambiar por ejemplo azul para el botón bueno y amarillo para el botón regular.

Estos botones quiero cambiar: https://mediterrane.es/SisCalificacion/wordpress/pagina-test-calidad-de-servicio/

```html
<div class="apm-answers apm-answers-without-submit ">
  <div class="apm-rating answer-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863">
   <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio-0-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863" value="18">
    <label for="radio-0-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863">
     <i class="ays_poll_far ays_poll_fa-star " style="content: url(&quot;https://i.ibb.co/gR8cKjZ/button23.png&quot;);"></i></label></div>
<div class="apm-rating answer-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863">            <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio-1-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863" value="19">                                               
    <label for="radio-1-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863">
     <i class="ays_poll_far ays_poll_fa-star "></i></label></div>
<div class="apm-rating answer-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863"><input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio-2-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863" value="20">                                                 
  <label for="radio-2-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863">
    <i class="ays_poll_far ays_poll_fa-star "></i></label></div>
<div class="apm-rating answer-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863">
   <input type="radio" name="answer" id="radio-3-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863" value="21">                                               
 <label for="radio-3-ays-poll-id-639b3b5357863">
   <i class="ays_poll_far ays_poll_fa-star "></i></label>
   </div></div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
  document.querySelector('.ays_poll_far').style.content = "url('https://i.ibb.co/gR8cKjZ/button23.png')";

});
```

```css
.ays_poll_far {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    content: url(https://i.ibb.co/6YX781r/buttonverde.png);
    z-index: 20;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede hacer de varias maneras, aunque sin ver el código exacto, yo diría que puedes usar selectores de css. Te recomiendo que mires en la documentación: [Enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

Básicamente consiste en poner selectores a una clase o identificador. En tu caso, si quieres seleccionar x elemento de una serie, sería algo así:

```
 .tuClase:first-child{ // aquí tu código css para el primer elemento }
 .tuClase:last-child{ // aquí tu código css para el último elemento }
 .tuClase:nth-child(2){ // aquí tu código css para el segundo elemento  }
```

Y así sucesivamente.

Suerte!

Comment: Hola como estas? siguiendo un tutorial, hice eso, pero no funcionó, ahi puse el código, la clase que tiene la imagen de botones es .ays_poll_far , le puse con content, porque el plugin que es poll maker venia con rating de estrellas.